# Using a method to call individual strings from an array (looping)

Tags: java, arrays, string

This is the question from my assignment that I am unsure of:

The class is to contain a public method nextWord(). When a new line is read, use the String method .split("\s+") to create an array of the words that are on the line. Each call to the nextWord() method is to return the next word in the array. When all of the words in the array have been processed, read the next line in the file. The nextWord()method returns the value null when the end of the file is reached.

I have read the file, and stored each individual string in an array called tokenz.

I'm not sure how I can have a method called "nextWord" which returns each individual word from tokenz one at a time. Maybe I don't understand the question?

The last part of the question is:

In your main class, write a method named processWords() which instantiates the MyReader class (using the String "A2Q2in.txt"). Then write a loop that obtains one word at a time from the MyReader class using the nextWord() method and prints each word on a new line.

I've thought of ways to do this but I'm not sure how to return each word from the nextWord method i'm supposed to write. I can't increase a count because after the String is returned, anything after the return statement cannot be reached because the method is done processing.

Any help would be appreciated, maybe I'm going about this the wrong way?

Can't use array lists or anything like that.

Here is my code.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class A2Q2
{ 

  public static void main (String [] args)
  {
    processWords();
  }

  public static void processWords()
  {
    MyReader reader = new MyReader("A2Q2.txt");

    String[] words = new String[174];

    words[0] = reader.nextWord();
    System.out.println(words[0]);

  }

}

class MyReader
{
  static String name;
  static BufferedReader fileIn;
  static String inputLine;
  static int tokensLength = 0;
  static String[] tokens;
  static int counter = 0;






  // constructor.
  public MyReader(String name)
  {
    this.name = name;
  }


  public static String[] readFile()
  {

    String[] tokenz = new String[174];
    int tokensLength = 0; 



    try
    {
      fileIn = new BufferedReader (new FileReader(name));
      inputLine = fileIn.readLine();



      while(inputLine !=null)
      {
        tokens = inputLine.split("\\s+");  

        for (int i = 0 ; i < tokens.length; i++)
        {
          int j = i + tokensLength;
          tokenz[j] = tokens[i];   
        }
        tokensLength = tokensLength + tokens.length; 
        inputLine = fileIn.readLine();
      }

      fileIn.close();

    }

    catch (IOException ioe)
    {
      System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
      ioe.printStackTrace();
    }  

    //FULL ARRAY OF STRINGS IN TOKENZ


    return tokenz;

  }

  public static String nextWord()
  {
    String[] tokenzz = readFile();
    //????
    return tokenzz[0];
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a conceptual model for you.

Keep track of your `MyReader`'s state to know which value to return next.
the following example uses `tokenIndex` to decide where to read at next.

```
class MyReader
{
  String[] tokens;

  int tokenIndex = 0;

  public String nextWord()
  {
    if(tokens == null || tokens.length <= tokenIndex)
    {
        // feel free to replace this line with whatever logic you want to
        // use to fill in a new line.
        tokens = readNextLine();
        tokenIndex = 0;
    }
    String retVal = tokens[tokenIndex];
    tokenIndex++;

    return retval;
  }   
}
```

Mind you, this isn't a complete solution(it doesn't check for the end of file for instance), only a demonstration of the concept.  You might have to elaborate a bit.

Comment: Notice that the tokenIndex variable above is keeping track of your state, which index you are processing.  You really only need to read one line at a time, and read another new line when your nextWord method exhausts words in the current array (tokenIndex>tokens.length).

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but once I call nextWord, don't all variables reset? (Won't  tokenIndex be 0 when called for a second time?).

EDIT: Realized I needed to initialize outside of the method. Thank you guys very much for the much needed different way of thinking.

Answer (score -1):

Use a loop and process each element in the array, printing them one at a time?